# Perl - Scan directory for pattern in contained filenames and fill array

Tags: arrays, perl, file, subroutine

i ve tried to write a simple function that takes two arguments, input directory and pattern, and returns an array with the matched files that contain the pattern(s) in their name.

```
my $dir = "/drives/D/Desktop/perlscripts";

sub getfiles
{
  my ($dirName, @patterns) = @_;
  opendir(my $dir, $dirName) or die "Can't open '$dirName': $!";
  my @return;
  for my $file (readdir($dir))
  {
    for my $pattern (@patterns)
    {
      if ($file =~ /$pattern/)
      { 
        print "$file \n";
        push @return, $file;
        # This avoids having the file in the result twice
        last;
      }
    }
   }

    return @return;
  }


 my @plscripts = getfiles($dir, "pl");
 print "@plscripts \n";
```

I get nothing in STDOUT with the code as is, after some tests, i think the problem is with the.

Edited with changes : As you can see i commented out #last; but yes it matches every file name on every iteration then. So i end up with duplicate entries in the array.

Comment: Why do you have `@ARGV` there? It carries _command line arguments_.  Change `@ARGV` to `@patterns` and it should work.  I'd also suggest that you return a reference to `@return` since that can turn out to be a long list.  Also, I don't get your `last` -- it breaks out of the loop over patterns after the first match (successful `if`), so you effectively test only for the first pattern in `@patterns`.

Comment: @zdim I'd thought so, too, at first glance, but the `last` breaks the inner loop, preventing a filename from matching more that one pattern.  Quite so re: `@ARGV`

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate the above script into one that does this recursively for all subdirectories? I basicly want to emulate the shell ls -lR | grep patterns.

Comment: @pilcrow  Um, correct -- thank you.  Supply a list `@patterns` to try but once the current file matches a pattern that's it, move onto the next file. I do get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick fix could be add a label for your first loop and then change the "last" to "next FILE":

```
my $dir = "/drives/D/Desktop/perlscripts";

sub getfiles
{
  my ($dirName, @patterns) = @_;
  opendir(my $dir, $dirName) or die "Can't open '$dirName': $!";
  my @return;
  FILE:
  for my $file (readdir($dir))
  {
    for my $pattern (@patterns)
    {
      if ($file =~ /$pattern/)
      { 
        print "$file \n";
        push @return, $file;
        # This avoids having the file in the result twice
        # last
        next FILE;
      }
    }
   }

    return @return;
  }


 my @plscripts = getfiles($dir, "pl");
 print "@plscripts \n";
```

Comment: Your comment is incorrect.  What you say does exactly the same as posted code.  It may be nicer or better but it is not a "_fix_". What fixes the problem is the change to `@patterns` from the OP"s `@ARGV`.

Comment: Well, for some strange reason I don't see any @ARGV ! Also this is a quick fix not the best.

Comment: Whoa ... in the original post there was `for my $pattern (@ARGV)`.  This is a fine change but I don't see how it affects processing at all, that's what I was saying.  Both ways exit the inner loop and continue iterating through the outter loop once `if` evaluates true in the inner loop.

Comment: Right -- and it is.  I think that the only error was that `@ARGV`, which then got fixed. (Possibly after comments popped up.)